# Query performance issue. Can I optimize this?

Tags: mysql

Ok, I have a query that I just can't seem to get optimized.  Maybe I am doing too much in MySQL and should delegate more to PHP.  The query as it is takes about a minute, but I really need it to be much faster than that.  Below is a hypothetical structure that should give you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

You will notice that I am supplying the query with a PHP variable, $bookList, which contains a list of book_id's owned by the current user in a comma delimited format.

For this example, assume that the user has 70 book_id's assigned to his library ($bookList) and he wants to find out which stores share the most books in common with his library.  Each store has 70 books, but there are 200,000+ stores.  Stores with less than 50% in common will be filtered out.

Table 1: my_books

```
id: mediumint
book_id: smallint
```

Table 2: store_books

```
store_id: mediumint
book_id: smallint
index: store_id
index: book_id
```

Table 3; stores

```
id: mediumint
name: varchar(50)
primary: id
```

Query:

```
SELECT count(s.book_id) AS commonBooks, s.id
                 FROM store_books AS sb
                 INNER JOIN stores AS s ON s.id = sb.id
                 WHERE sb.book_id IN ($bookList) 
                 GROUP BY sb.store_id 
                 HAVING commonBooks > 35
                 ORDER BY commonBooks
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean for sb.id on the inner join to be sb.store_id?

Comment: I think you need a compound index in table `store_books`. on `(store_id,book_id)`

Comment: You should also replace `count(s.book_id)` with `count(*)`

Comment: The idea with declarative queries is that the db engine is supposed to optimize them for you. To that end SQL Server provides a Query Analyzer (or something), which tries your query and tells you which indicies you should build to speed it up. Maybe there's a similar tool for MySQL?

Comment: @Gleno, yes there is it is called EXPLAIN [extended] SELECT: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from @Joe Stefanelli's answer, use the temp table.
Make sure you have the primary index on bl.book_id

*BTW: You seem to have an error in your query:*

```
SELECT count(*) AS commonBooks, s.id
FROM store_books AS sb
INNER JOIN stores AS s ON s.id = sb.store_id  -- <<sb.store_id, not sb.id
WHERE sb.book_id IN (SELECT bl.book_id FROM tempBookList)
GROUP BY sb.store_id 
HAVING commonBooks > 35
ORDER BY commonBooks DESC
```

It's a little known fact that MySQL can only use one index per (sub)select.
Make sure you have a composite index in table `store_book`
Also `count(*)` is *(sometimes)* faster than `count(afield)` *(and never slower)*

```
Table 2: store_books

store_id: mediumint
book_id: smallint
index: (store_id, book_id)  <<-- composite primary index.
index: (book_id)
```

This query will run faster in InnoDB than MyISAM because InnoDB can use covering indexes to resolve this query and will not need to read the data in the actual tables.

Comment: Is there any reason that the composite index shouldn't be PRIMARY?  I am currently in the process of porting this entire project to Symfony on the side which should only use INNODB.  Hopefully that will help as you may suggest.

Comment: @IOInterrupt, o contrare the composite index **must** be primary.

Comment: Just wanted to drop in and say thanks.  First of all thank you for actually explaining your suggestions, this was much more helpful than just saying "do this" without any sort of explanation of why to do so.

Comment: Would it be more efficient to use an INNER join on the temp table or us the IN with a sub select?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd extract the values from $bookList into a temporary table and replace the IN with a JOIN against that temporary table.

```
SELECT count(s.book_id) AS commonBooks, s.id
                 FROM store_books AS sb
                 INNER JOIN stores AS s ON s.id = sb.id
                 INNER JOIN tempBookList AS bl ON sb.book_id = bl.book_id
                 GROUP BY sb.store_id 
                 HAVING commonBooks > 35
                 ORDER BY commonBooks
```

Comment: Well my_books does have those id's.  You think it would be faster to join against that table, rather than using IN?

Comment: @IOInterrupt I do. It's certainly worth trying.